# How is Na concentration re-established after action potential

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, action-potential

I understand that the repolarization is because some K+ chanels are opened with the action potential. But whats happens with the sodium chemical gradient that is needed for a new action potential? Are there further Na-K pumps in the axon membrane?

Comment: Na+/K+ pumps are extremely ubiquitous. I recall reading that 1/3rd of an average cell's energy budget goes to maintaining that gradient, with neurons bringing this up to 2/3rds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are Na-K pumps all over.

However, it is important to recognize that ion concentrations change very little during action potentials. The change in membrane potential is due to changes in ion *conductances*, very few ions actually flow. It is still necessary to maintain concentration gradients over many many action potentials, but the change in concentrations during the course of a single action potential is negligible.

Comment: Probably too late to ask but I'd love an explanation for the downvote.

Comment: No not too late. Just a lack of sources. Also the fact it's a four liner makes it a bit of a content less answer. Ping me once updated. Happy to upvote.

Comment: Heck, the question is quite poor too. Poor question, mediocre answer. I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @AliceD If you want to merge it with https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57064/why-is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-equilibrium-potential-of-an-ion-using-the-ne that could be done, I like my answer better there anyways. Might need to make a new canonical answer and question to fit all those types of questions though, because there are a variety of questions people ask that deserve basically exactly the same response.