# How Fast can the Electrochemical Gradient on a Neuron be Reestablished?

Tags: neuroscience, electrophysiology, membrane-transport

[The electrochemical gradient](https://alg.manifoldapp.org/read/fundamentals-of-cell-biology/section/f4d10886-6492-41bb-9ab0-bbbc67bb0292) of Na<sup>+</sup>, K<sup>+</sup>, Ca<sup>2+</sup>, and Cl<sup>-</sup> between the inside and outside of a neuron is vital for its function. When a neuron fires, this gradient reverses. How long does it take for the gradient to be re-established?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/57064/27148 Gradients don't reverse during an action potential, only permeabilities chance substantially. Yes, a few ions do move and pumps are needed to restore concentrations, but it's very few ions.

Comment: Also https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/76167/27148

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although I knew the voltage change, I didn't realize how few ions are actually needed to cause that change. If you post an answer saying the same thing I'll pick it as correct.