# Doubt related to nerve impulse transmission

Tags: molecular-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology, action-potential

Naturally, the extracellular fluid has more sodium ions and the axoplasm has more potassium ions. Since there are more potassium leakage channels than sodium leakage channels on axoplasm, it is more permeable to potassium ions moving out into the extracellular fluid.

Is it correct to assume, due to this huge outflux of potassium ions into the extracellular fluid, there are more potassium ions than sodium ions in the extracellular fluid now?

Comment: You can look up any table of the intracellular composition of nerve cells, and actually any other cell, that K+ is always high inside. You should attempt to include some of your prior research and specifically tell us what you don't understand.

Comment: The question is different but see if this answer clears it up for you https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/57066/27148 tldr: very very few ions move to change a cells' voltage.

Comment: @AliveD I know K+ is always high inside (axoplasm), but the thing I wanted to know is, at that particular region and time, after the leakage channels do their job, is the concentration of K+ in extracellular fluid more than Na+?

Comment: Check the answer I linked to.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks a lot! I got the answer (similar) to what I was looking for.

Comment: One friendly correction. The Indian English usage of the word “doubt” to mean “query” or “question” is not standard US or British English. It’s difficult, I know, but you should try not to use it Internationally. It can be misleading as it suggests that you do not believe some person or idea.

Comment: @David Okay! I'll take care of that.